# How to store and read different language strings in xml file using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to store different language(like Hindi,Tamil,etc) data to a xml file then have to read same data using C# .How to do that?

Comment: Please elaborate. Are you asking how to write text to xml and then afterwards read it back in?

Comment: @Sathyaraj P, You may store language IDs using XML nodes attributes (language codes as defined in RFC 5646 format: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5646)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may store language IDs using XML nodes attributes (language codes as defined in [RFC 5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646) format)

Specifically, according to question, India "Hindi", language code is described [here](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html), as "hi", so you can add XML Attribute named "lang" with value of requested language. In your case you may use "hi" for "Hindi"

I am personally use language attributes

For example, you may using language attributes for XML data nodes as follows:

```
<resource lang="ru-RU" name="Title">
йцуйцуйцуйуйцуйцуйцу
</resource>
<resource lang="en-US" name="Title">
asdasdasdasdasdasdas
</resource>
```